# Get the keyboard event in android

Tags: android, webview, key-events

I am having webview,page having search functionality when user focus the view to serch android keyboard open and i want to handle ime options.

In android keyboard i have ime option as "GO" button.
I have search a lot for this,and tried lot everything except though my pc outside the window please help me how can i do that

here is my code i am not getting toast or log values.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
        Toast.makeText(key.this, "preseed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("d", "preseed");
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F:
        Log.e("f", "preseed");
        Toast.makeText(key.this, "preseed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_J:
        Log.e("j", "preseed");
        Toast.makeText(key.this, "preseed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K:
        Log.e("k", "preseed");
        Toast.makeText(key.this, "preseed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onEditorActionListener on your search view as follow:

```
  editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView view,
                final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {

            if (event != null && actionId != 7 && actionId != 5) {
                  //manage press of button 7 and 5


            } else {
                activity.hideKeyboard();
                return false;
            }

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                 //manage press of enter button

            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: I have webview not android edittext.
That i know how to use ime option with android edittext

Comment: Pardon:)Have you tried to log your event.getKeyCode() to see if at least the event is caught??